# Math manuals in chez scheme

Tags: chez-scheme

I could apply functions of sqrt and sin as

```
> (sqrt 35)
5.916079783099616
> (sin 1.57)
0.9999996829318346
```

in chez scheme's interactive shell,

but I cannot reference them in [Chapter 8. Numeric Operations](https://www.scheme.com/csug8/numeric.html)

Where are their manuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for math functions in *The Scheme Programming Language, Fourth Edition*, [Section 6.4. Numbers](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:h4):

- [`sqrt`](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:s127)
- [`sin`](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:s131)